# TeamsFx - Is custom settings possible with Blazor IConfiguration?

Tags: blazor, microsoft-teams, blazor-webassembly, teams-toolkit

How would you go about saving settings for each user who uses your app? I am still somewhat new with using Blazor and it isn't clear on how to tell what is globally being cached and what is user cached currently. The extra layer of the TeamsFX SDK makes it harder to understand how to integrate or use this concept. Each user needs their own .json file for custom settings I am creating in some way.

I am asking here because GitHub redirects to stackexchange when asking questions about the TeamsFX SDK. Without TeamsFX it looks like IConfiguration would be the answer, but I cannot tell if this same method would work with TeamsFX being involved.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I have noticed on starting pages it has:
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

Can I bind to this? Would I need to bind for each loaded page? Would information be stored for each user indefinitely or is it just session based?

Comment: _"Each user needs their own .json file"_ - then each user will need a distinct URL to download it from. Have you thought about security?

Comment: This is just for theme information and other basic settings. I already created an internal way to save .json files based on the user logged in and secured information is not handled with Blazor. This seems to be a good way to do it, but I was looking for a more official way with how Blazor works.

Comment: Did that work for 2+ users?

Comment: That's what I need to test somehow. I unfortunately don't have multiple licenses for Teams App testing at that level. I was hoping to find details on here. This is pretty new, and information does appear to be scarce.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid now TeamsFx do not support such scenario. You need to use something more common, yes IConfiguration will also be my choice.
Here's a suggestion, if you want to have a testing tenant with 20+ user to testing in Teams, Microsoft 365 developer sandbox subscription is the best way. The link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program-get-started